# Is my Canon setup good enough for Astrophotography

Tags: canon, astrophotography, canon-50d

To start off I'm totally new to Astrophotography.
So I got a old camera from my grandpa.

its the **Canon EOS 50D**.
with as lens the:
**CANON EF-S 18-200MM IS F/3.5-5.6**

But I'm not sure how capable it is for the job.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get started in Astrophotography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/how-do-i-get-started-in-astrophotography)

Comment: There is a treasure trove of knowledge in the astrophotography tag: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrophotography?tab=Votes

Comment: Related: [What lens characteristics are important in star photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/43114/15871) and [What should I look for in a camera for Night Sky Photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/113114/15871) and [astrophotography with Nikon D3300 is possible?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/56941/15871)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's entirely a matter of opinion whether it's "good enough". Using a simple point-and-shoot camera on time-lapse and manual settings, I've made a video of a lunar eclipse that *satisfied me* and that others found interesting. It did not rival photos from the [University of Toronto dragonfly array](https://www.dunlap.utoronto.ca/instrumentation/dragonfly/), though.

Use what you have, learn how to make images and to improve your technique, and *then*, if you desire, try other equipment. "[Technique, technique, technique](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/c5141220-c763-4dca-a4ca-b36163a188de)."

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on doing serious astrophotography I suggest using a good prime lens instead of a zoom.  Corner sharpness and chroma control are very important.  Also, read all the guides you can find and be prepared to purchase stacking software.